# where/how to store an image private to my app? (Android)

Tags: android

I've got a image selector/cropper with code taken from [this site](http://www.androidworks.com/crop_large_photos_with_android)

They create the image in the phone's external storage but I want to store this in my app's internal storage, a process documented [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal)

This is what my function to retrieve the temp file looks like, however when I try to use the file returned from this function, the image does not change. In fact, looking at logcat, it seems resolveUri failed on bad bitmap uri on that file I generated. The error occurs when I try to set the Image URI, leading me to believe it was not saved properly. This is odd to me considering the original code from the site just creates a file in the SD card, and the code works fine for reading/writing to that. So I wonder where the problem arises.

```
@Override
  public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    switch (requestCode) {
    case PHOTO_PICKED:
      if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (data != null) {
          Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
          if (extras != null) {
            ImageView callerImage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.contact_image);
            callerImage.setImageURI(Uri.fromFile(getTempFile()));
          }
        }
      }
      break;
    }
  }

private File getTempFile() {
    try {
      FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(TEMP_PHOTO_FILE, Context.MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE);
      fos.close();
      File f = getFileStreamPath(TEMP_PHOTO_FILE);
      return f;
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
      // To be logged later
      return null;
    } catch (IOException e) {
      // To be logged later
      return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is TEMP_PHOTO_FILE set to? According to the docs, it must not contain any path separators.

Comment: it's set to "tempPhoto.jpg", the same as the source code I linked. I was able to make this work earlier by just creating a new File in the file system, instead of using openFileOutput, so I have to think the problem lies there somewhere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, I am so silly. When I called getTempFile, each time it recreates the file, which is a mistake. It should only create the file on the initial call and simply open it the rest of the time.